# JS async functions execute in random order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, async-await

I have an async function making an api request. Once completed, it calls a different async function making an api request 4 times (intended to go in the order it's called). But every time it runs, those api requests return data in a random order.

First, I call `fetchSearch`, this works as expected.

```js
    const fetchSearch = async () => {
        var myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("x-app-id", "...");
        myHeaders.append("x-app-key", "...");
        
        var requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
        redirect: 'follow'
        };
        
        await fetch(`https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/search/instant?query=${search}`, requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(
            result => (
                handleSearch(JSON.parse(result).common)
            )
        )
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
    }
```

This calls `handleSearch`. I'm probably doing something wrong here.

```js
    const handleSearch = (data) => {
        const dataList=[]
        for (var key in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                dataList.push(data[key])
            }
        }
        if (dataList[0] !== undefined) {
            setSearchResults([dataList[0], dataList[1], dataList[2], dataList[3]])
            fetchNutrition(dataList[0].food_name)
                .then(() => {fetchNutrition(dataList[1].food_name)})
                .then(() => {fetchNutrition(dataList[2].food_name)})
                .then(() => {fetchNutrition(dataList[3].food_name)})
        } else {
            setSearchError(true)
        }
    }
```

`handleSearch` calls `fetchNutrition`:

```js
    const fetchNutrition = async (foodName) => {
        var h = new Headers();
        h.append("accept", "application/json");
        h.append("x-app-id", "...");
        h.append("x-app-key", "...");
        h.append("x-remote-user-id", "1");
        h.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: h,
            body: JSON.stringify({ "query": foodName }),
            redirect: 'follow'
        }

        await fetch("https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(result => {setNutritionResults(nutritionResults => [...nutritionResults, JSON.parse(result)])})
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
    }
```

With an array of 4 strings from `fetchSearch`, `handleSearch` and `fetchNutrition` should be going through each string and adding the corresponding nutrition JSON string to the `nutritionResults` array state (in the correct order in the array).

Every time it runs, all the nutrition results are returned in a random order in the `nutritionResults` array, and I'm assuming it's because `handleSearch` isn't calling the functions in the correct order. Or I'm missing another issue.

For example, if `fetchSearch` returns `["apple", "apples", "apple juice", "apple pie"]`, `nutritionResults` will end up as an array of length 4 but in a random order every time it runs.

Comment: for a start, `handleSearch` will start the `fetchNutrition` and keep executing without waiting for it, since, you don't wait for it - also, mixing `async`/`await` with `.then`/`.catch` is never a good idea

Comment: `fetch()` requests complete when they complete. You cannot rely on any particular order.

Comment: not a real issue, but `.then(response => response.text()).then(result => ..... JSON.parse(result) ...)` ... why not use `response.json()` then you won't need to `JSON.parse` the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `handleSearch()` is not `await`ing `fetchNutrition()`. Therefore the code continues without waiting - exactly as described.

To fix this all you need to do is wait for `fetchNutrition()` to complete:

```
const handleSearch = async (data) => {
    // ...

        await fetchNutrition(dataList[0].food_name)
            .then(() => {return fetchNutrition(dataList[1].food_name)})
            .then(() => {return fetchNutrition(dataList[2].food_name)})
            .then(() => {return fetchNutrition(dataList[3].food_name)})
    // ...
}
```

Note: The `return` in front of `fetchNutrution()` is important if you want `await` to wait for it to complete. Otherwise `await` will not wait for it because there is no `Promise` returned by the chain of `.then()`.

Alternatively this does the exact same thing:

```
const handleSearch = (data) => {
    // ...

        return fetchNutrition(dataList[0].food_name)
            .then(() => {return fetchNutrition(dataList[1].food_name)})
            .then(() => {return fetchNutrition(dataList[2].food_name)})
            .then(() => {return fetchNutrition(dataList[3].food_name)})

    // NOTE: The bugfix is adding a "return" 
    // ...
}
```

Either of the above will cause `handleSearch()` to return a Promise which can be awaited.

Now you also need to allow `fetchSearch()` to `await` `handleSearch()`. Similar to the above you can add a `return` to do this:

```
    await fetch(`https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/search/instant?query=${search}`, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(
        result => (
            return handleSearch(JSON.parse(result).common)

            // Note: The bugfix is adding the return above
            // so that this chain of .then() will return the
            // handleSearch() Promise which the above await
            // will wait for
        )
    )
```

Alternatively you could also do the following to allow `fetchSearch()` to wait for `handleSearch()`:

```
    await fetch(`https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/search/instant?query=${search}`, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(
        result => handleSearch(JSON.parse(result).common)
    )

    // Note: The bugfix is removing the braces "()" around
    // handleSearch() causing js to add an implicit "return"
```

Another alternative is to avoid mixing async/await with .then() chains altogether:

```
    const response = await fetch(`https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/search/instant?query=${search}`, requestOptions)
    const result = await response.text()

    await handleSearch(JSON.parse(result).common)
```

Comment: You also need to add `return`s to the `then` chain callbacks

Comment: @Bergi Well spotted

Answer (score 0):

I think you use await is shorten than promise.then.
Try this:

```
const handleSearch = async (data) => {
   ...
   await fetchNutrition(dataList[1].food_name)
   await fetchNutrition(dataList[2].food_name)
   await fetchNutrition(dataList[3].food_name)
   ...
}
```

Comment: Don't use nested `.then()`. The whole idea of Promises is that you can remove nesting. Just do flat `.then()` exactly the same as you would with `await`

Comment: @slebetman yeah, i will remove it